# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise has empty $location.search()

Tags: angular-ui-router

I've defined some states and want to use a fallback state/url defined with `otherwise`. Because the states do not define the root url '/' (I have no view for this state) but the app may be started by this url with some optional query params, I tried to use the function call of `otherwise` to keep possibly given params.
But when the `otherwise` function is called, the `$location.search()` is empty, although the url looks like `localhost:9002/?ac=1`.

Maybe a side effect will be that the given url will be rewritten to `localhost:9002/?ac=1#/search` although I would expect the url to be rewritten to `localhost:9002/#/search?ac=1`.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location)
{
    var state = $injector.get('$state');
    console.log('location', $location, 'location.search()', $location.search());
    state.go('search', $location.search());
    return $location.path();
});

$stateProvider
    .state('search',
    {
        url: '/search',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
    })
    .state('displays',
    {
        url: '/displays',
        templateUrl: 'templates/displays.html'
    })
    .state('favorites',
    {
        url: '/favorites',
        templateUrl: 'templates/favorites.html'
    })
    .state('detail',
    {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailController'
    });
```

Is this a real error of the ui-router or am I just handling this use case the wrong way?

**Note** I'm not using the html5mode. Is this a "must have" for this use case?

I'm not sure if the topic fits the source of the problem, so please let me know if I'm wrong.

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just do this:
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('', 'search');`